# qooxdoo : qx.ui.window.Window.center() warning

Tags: qooxdoo

When I issue `.center()` on a `qx.ui.window.Window()`, qooxdoo F7 log shows the following warning :

> Centering depends on parent bounds!

How can I clear the warning ?

My code is as follow :

```
var win = new myApp.MyWindow(); // myApp.MyWindow extends qx.ui.window.Window()
win.center();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add the window to a parent or open it before you center it. Opening will add the window to the root automatically which will also solve the problem. If you don't want to open it, just add the window to you applications root manually.